How to check or setup /dev/device belong to which group
In a Chinese blog that I followed for compiling Mali GPU drivers following paragraph I cannot understand

After restarting, check that /dev/video-enc0 and /dev/video-dec0
should exist and belong to the group "video". At the same time, the
logged-in user should also have the "video" group permissions to
perform hardware encoding and hard encoding.

I have compiled GPU & the said devices exist, but I don't know how to setup or check the device ownership stuff

It doesn't seem to be asking for anything more complicated than ls -ld /dev/video-{enc,dec}0

& should I add myself to video group?

Yes. Do sudo adduser  $USER video, then logoff/logon. Groups are assigned at logon.
